# Logstash input plugin: Redis vs Elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, redis, logstash

I was wondering about which input plugin would be a better choice for a middle-sized application. I'm currently using the service for logging everything in my app, using Monolog's Redis handler over PHP server. There are dozens of possibilities, but both Redis and Elasticsearch are more accessible to me so far. The points I'd consider to be important are:

- performance
- scalability
- maintenance
- pricing

Regarding performance, I've chosen Redis due to its own transfer protocol, which make the data traffic way simpler and faster.
However, I have seen many people opting for the Elasticsearch API.

I'd be thankful to have any suggestion about this topic or discuss about a better data input method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal scalability of ElasticSearch is there for quite some time, versus Redis Cluster which is new.

Also ElasticSearch allows you rich full text queries, Redis does not.

Also Logstash is from the same company which made ElasticSearch.

(My 2 cents from skimming through ElasticSearch book and using Redis in production for quite some time (which was better for my needs, no full text search and no more than one shard)).